# Why is this code resulting "unresolved reference"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a fairly easy Python3 script, which also uses [Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/):

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(id='mydiv', ...)

fff = False

@app.callback(
    Output('mydiv', '...'),
    Input('mydiv', 'myevent')
def update(evt):
    print(fff)
    return dash.no_update
```

This correctly prints 'False' when the `update` function is called on click on the div.

However, a slight modification makes python not interpret my whole file:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(id='mydiv', ...)

fff = False

@app.callback(
    Output('mydiv', '...'),
    Input('mydiv', 'myevent')
def update(evt):
    *** print(fff)
    fff = True
    return dash.no_update
```

This makes "Unresolved reference 'fff'" in line marked with ***

If I put "nonlocal fff" in front of that unresolved reference line, there is a syntax error of

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'fff' found
```

Why is this happening? Why can the python print *fff*'s value if I don't want to modify it?

And how can I modify it in this `update` function?

Comment: You've defined a local variable which shadows the *global* name `fff`. It doesn't matter where in the scope the assignment occurs; just the *presence* of the assignment makes the code generator mark the name as local (even if the assignment is never executed at runtime).

Comment: An assignment to a variable in a function (anywhere in that function) will cause the compiler to mark the variable as local. If you want to assign to a global variable in your function then you can use the `global` statement, although mutating global state is generally an antipattern

Comment: You also appear to be missing the closing parenthesis for `@app.callback`.